# The usage of "so that" with the present continuous

Tags: conjunctions

Is it correct to use the present continuous with SO THAT?

Give him what he wants so that he is not nagging at you.

I will show you how to do it so that you you working now.

Comment: Most people would say _so that he will stop nagging you_ or _so that he won't nag you_.

Comment: Your first sentence is not idiomatic. Your second, with an obviously incorrect repetition of the word **you**, is hard to understand.

Comment: Is the present continuous not possible with SO THAT at all?